# Android adb unable connect with ip address

Tags: java, android

I have installed android operating system in Oracle Virtual box successfully.

but I am facing one problem ,

I tried many options, but I couldn't solve this problem .

My problem is - **I am not able to adb connect to virtual box android os.**

[image]

When i am selecting **host-only Adapter** option ,easy to connect with adb but **no internet** connection in android virtual box os.

[image]
When i am selecting **NAT** ,Internet connection fine but not connect with adb .
[image]

Please help me how to solve my problem ..

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I solved my problem. This was my solution:

In the emulator press the CTRL + Home keys and press Devices > Network Adapters.

[image: Screenshot with results of pressing the keys]

See the menu, select Network and select Bridged Adapter.

[image: Screenshot of the configurations]

Press CTRL + ALT + F1 in the emulator to open the Android terminal and type the following command:

`netcfg`

[image: Example result of netcfg]

Press CTRL + ALT + F7 to see the Graphical View.

Restart the emulator.
Use the found IP in the command:

`adb connect <IP address>`

Answer (score 2):

At first **enable adb over tcpip** in the Android VM Terminal Emulator.

Type the command #

> adb tcpip 5555

Then to connect via adb from a command line

Type the command #

> adb connect 219.91.220.142

**Further resources:**

- [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)
- [Android - adb tcpip error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074868/android-adb-tcpip-error)
- [Android x86 on VirtualBox: Android Connected But Not Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760490/android-x86-on-virtualbox-android-connected-but-not-online)

Comment: how to enable adb over tcpip in terminal ?

Comment: To enable adb over tcpip run the command # adb tcpip 555, which I already added in my answer.

Comment: Your TCIP daemon is not running.

Comment: @AndroidRevolution Please have a look at "further resources" portion of my answer.

Comment: i got it my answer ..see following ways see in answer.

Comment: Hint: When you enter the first command `adb tcpip 5555` the device must be connected via USB.