# Connecting ADB using Wifi for non rooted device

Tags: android, port, adb

I am trying to connect ADB using WIFI on my non rooted android devices. Currently i have 3 android devices out of which 2 are running on Android 4.0.4 and 1 on 2.3.
My device IP's are 192.168.2.122, 192.168.2.131, 192.168.2.115

I have enabled USB debugging on all of them and follow all the steps as listed [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

On the command line, I did the following

```
adb tcpip 5555
restarting in TCP mode port:5555 
adb connect 192.168.2.131
```

My problem is on one of my device(Android 4.0.4) ADB is getting connected with the message saying

```
connected to 192.168.2.122:5555
```

However when i try connecting other it says

```
unable to connect to 192.168.2.131:5555
```

Screenshot of the terminal page:
[image: Screenshot of the terminal page:]

Image of terminal on the connected device:
[image]

Image of terminal on device which is not getting connected:
[image]

Many of the posts on Stack Over Flow says i need to root my phone for the same but the device on which ADB is getting connected is also not rooted.

May be the problem with the devices not getting connected is that their ports are not getting listened.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14357705/1626878

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Sahil, i have done the same and adb is connected to one of the device also but for the other devices adb is not getting connected. Please help if possible how to connect all of my devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works perfect with android 4.0.4. but, below that it does not works. 
so, the answer to your problem is to upgrade all devices to 4.0.4.

Answer (score 71):

I had the same problem.

I firstly connected my Android4.0.3 based device via USB and set the TCP/IP port to 5555

```
$ adb tcpip 5555
```

After that I disconnected USB connection and connected to device via WiFi IP and it worked.

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb connect 192.168.2.5 
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 192.168.2.5:5555
```

Comment: Is your device rooted?
I have an non-rooted device but its failing to connect.

Comment: This worked for me on a rooted HTC Hero running Android 2.3.7 - thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question for _non rooted_ devices without USB connection.

Comment: Make sure: that you do not have `Android studio` running before executing the - 'restart adb in tcpip mode' command.

Comment: Working on Android 6.0.1 without any issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Working on Lollipop (Motorola Moto G)

Answer (score 24):

The steps are correct, with one small part different: the connect step has to be done after taking out the cable. 
To reiterate follow the steps exactly as below and it will work for non-rooted devices also. I tested it with several non-rooted devices including Moto G, Nexus 1, Videocon etc.

1. Attach mobile via USB and type:

   ```
   adb tcpip 5555
   ```
2. To find the mobile ip type:

   ```
   adb shell ip -f inet addr show wlan0
   ```

The ip address will be shown in second line like this:

```
inet 192.168.1.233/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
```

where 192.168.1.233 is the ip address of your mobile.

3. Remove USB cable and type:

   ```
   adb connect mobile-ip:5555
   ```

Comment: Make sure: that you do not have Android studio running before executing the - 'restart adb in tcpip mode' command.

Comment: If you have IDE running then adb may have been already started and you may need to restart it in some cases:
adb kill-server; adb start-server

Answer (score 8):

After read this question I decided to create a easy to use solution to fix this problem. You can use an open source IntelliJ Plugin I've developed. [Here](https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB) is the code and [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7983) the plugin ready to be used.

The usage is quite simple. Here you have a gif:

[image]

Remember that old devices using an Android 2.X does not support this Android Debug Bridge feature. That's why you can't connect the device you show in the screenshots.

Comment: This error is coming "adb command not found, review your andorid sdk Installation" error  when i run this plugin.You have any idea how to resolve that.

Comment: I've just tried it, any way to speed up apk install?  It is taking longer than via usb.

Comment: Hi Nick!

It's not possible to speed up the installation from the plugin code. Sorry. The only way you could improve the installation time is to get a faster WiFi connection or a faster ADB. The plugin is just executing commands programmatically. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Screenshot of the terminal page]

first connect device using USB

then apply the commands....

Answer (score 0):

Turn on adb over wifi on your phone
[image]

Then create file on your desktop ex. 'connect.bat'
and paste this code (you have to only change sdk, port and ip):

```
SET sdk=F:\Praca\sdk\platform-tools
SET port=5555
SET ip=192.168.1.101

cd /dd %sdk%
adb tcpip "%port%"
adb shell netcfg
adb connect  "%ip%:%port%"
echo connected by WiFi
pause
adb -s "%ip%:%port%" usb
echo disconnected
pause
```

It's really fast and simply solution. Have fun!