# How to connect my PC to my Android with ADB wireless connections?

Tags: android

I am new to android.

Is there any way to connect the wireless adb to my PC?

I've gone through many free apps which are not allowing me to connect when my PC doesn't have internet connection

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357705/adb-over-wireless/14357876#14357876

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible using this free app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wave18.adbwireless

I am not sure have you ever used it or not

Comment: The app that you have mentioned is not available on Play Store anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are a lot of applications for wireless ADB connection for rooted devices. In case of non rooted devices, it is possible to establish ADB session over wifi, however, you'll have to connect your device to the PC over USB first:

1. Connect your device to PC via USB
2. Set the TCP/IP port to 5555:

   $ adb tcpip 5555
3. Disconnect your device (via USB) and then reconnect it over WiFi (do ping test to verify)
4. Execute the following:

   $ adb kill-server
   $ adb connect 192.168.2.5

   - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
   - daemon started successfully *
     connected to 192.168.2.5:5555

Now, you'll be able to run ADB commands over WiFi.