# Test Android app with bluetooth

Tags: android

am having problems with when connection my phone to laptop(screen goes crazy) and its impossible to test apps, so I was wondering is it possible to connect via bluetooth so that apk is built and I can test them on phone? ty

Comment: You can do so via wifi. Check out this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357705/adb-over-wireless

Answer (score 0):

These links will help you. For Linux:

http://zcourts.com/2013/07/19/android-debugging-over-bluetooth-without-root/#sthash.ZPG8TrnC.dpbs

For Windows:

http://blog.wijono.org/2014/01/android-connecting-adb-to-physical.html