# Wireless USB Debugging for Android Studio in MAC

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-wireless

Hello i want to connect my android in debugging mode with android studio

without usb cable

i am using mac os

Comment: Take a look to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357705/adb-over-wireless

Comment: If you can connect your device over wifi then what all you need to do is run : $ adb connect <IP address of android device>
It'll connect you to the android device over network.

Comment: OP said without usb cable.  All of these answers say that you first need to connect using a usb cable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1- connect your PC and Mobile to same network (WIFI)

now find IP

-open setting > WIFI >info of connected wireless network and then get STATIC IP from there

[image]

2- Now open teminal and then goto PATH paltform-tools in SDK then fire below command

-Connect the device via USB and make sure debugging is working.
-go to developer options from settings and follow below snap shots
[image]

3 - now in terminal ./adb connect `<DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>`:5555 (if your using windows then remove ./)

you show this output  - connected to 192.168.1.109:5555

now Disconnect USB .
and perform below command to start wireless debugging

adb -s `<DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>`:5555 usb

4- for disconnect device follow below commands

adb disconnect `<DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>`:5555

Comment: Step 3: had to do   adb connect <MOBILE-IP-ADDRESS>:5555

Comment: Tried to fix the adb connect <MOBILE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555 line, but it seems that the markdown already contains this change, just not showing up...

Comment: I don't know why but this doesn't seem to be working. Rather, I did
adb tcpip 5555
disconnected usb
adb connect <MOBILE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555
It got connected then

Comment: getting connect refused error
followed all the steps
failed to connect to '192.168.32.247:5555': Connection refused

Comment: is it possible to connect first time without USB? new MacBook does not have USB port :(

Comment: The question specifies `without usb cable`, but the answer states `Connect the device via USB`

Answer (score 11):

1. Firstly, connect your device to mac with cable.
2. Open the terminal and write `Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb tcpip 5555`. If u can't then right only `cd` then write `Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb tcpip 5555`
3. Then write `Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb connect YOUR_DEVICE_IP:5555`
4. After that you can see connected response
5. You can disconnect the cable and debug with WIFI.

Answer (score 10):

Almost same steps as the Dharmik Ghori's answer

Just that in step **3** you do:
`./adb tcpip 5555` instead of `./adb connect <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this [jetbrain plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7983-android-wifi-adb). Connect your device using a USB cable and press the Android WiFi ADB button. Once the device is connected over WiFi you dont need USB.