# How to ADB USB Debugging Mode without USB Cable

Tags: android, usb, adb

The USB cable interface of my phone is slightly broken, only supporting charging now. I cannot connect it to the PC to share files over MTP or USB Dedubugging with ADB.

Because USB Dedebugging is not working, I cannot uninstall some system apps with PC-side command "adb pm uninstsall --user 0 package_names". Is there other ways to **uninstall them without connecting to PC** (not rooted device).

I also tried to install JuiceSSH in the phone, and suppose to run "pm uninstall ..", but the command failed for not authorized. I am not sure whether only ADB USB Debugging mode can allow users to execute that command correctly?

My main goal is just to uninstall those system apps on the un-rooted device. I am pretty sure that ADB mode should work if my USB cable was not broken. Are there alternative ways to archive this goal (e.g. to enable ADB shell bypass USB cable, or some command in JuiceSSH to allow me to execute "pm uninstall --user 0 ..")?

Comment: Make sure both laptop and device connect with same WIFI. please follow this link https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-without-root

Comment: @Ali this still needs initial cable connection for enabling wireless feature (first line in linked tutorial: `You need to connect your device to your computer via USB cable`)... then you may disconnect cable and use wireless as long as both devices are connected to same WiFi

Comment: Yes for connection for first time you need to connect. after successfully connected you can remove the cable. @snachmsm

Comment: so this isn't a solution for user without any cable (or only broken one without possibility of even single connection)

Comment: Yes I agree with you. @snachmsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sadly, no, without root you can't execute this command. if you could then any app could uninstall any other, thats very insecure for user

you have to connect to your PC at least once for enabling ADB wireless connection ([check out how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357705/adb-over-wireless))

starting Android 11 there is and [ADB Wireless debug mode](https://medium.com/@urvesh/android-11s-wireless-debugging-5d0f6448ee3) built-in, it doesn't need any cable connection, even initial. but still limited to currently newest OS version...

Comment: Thanks, my Android is 6.0, and I no longer have even one chance to connect to PC for network configuration any more. This even blocks me to do device root, or reflush ROM if rooting device failed.

Comment: thats true, USB cable is mandatory... maybe just buy one or two for spare...?

Comment: The broken part is phone-side USB cable "slot", some PINs related to data transfer is destroyed. So reparing it is very troublesome. I think I need to bug a new phone.

Comment: well, one of rooting ways is to drop some file on sd card and load it in fastboot, some other devices can be rooted using even some app... if your device is a bit old (6.0) then there is a big chance of multiple ways of root (exploits discovered, device without multiple security patches). anyway, good luck! :)