# Android adb wireless debugging Huawei device

Tags: android, adb

I just purchased Huawei MatePad T8 tablet with Android 10. I enabled developer options and I can debug it via micro USB cable.

I would like to set wireless debugging. I kill adb server, shut down Android Studio and connect my device using USB cable. Then I issue commands:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.1.14:5555
```

And I get my two adb devices (same device, but once via USB cable and the second one is wireless debugging) succesfully connected to my PC:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
8TU9X20428K01472        device
```

I then disconnect USB cable and then I get:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.1.14:5555       offline
```

No matter how many times I repeat this process I always get my device offline and I can't wirelessly debug. Tablet's wifi works (I can browse web pages). Can you advise how to enable wireless debugging on Huawei MatePad T8? FYI: I have never had any problem enabling wireless debugging on any device I got in my hand.

Comment: Just checking! Are both your devices on the same network?

Comment: Yes, they are (otherwise I won't see 192.168.1.14:5555       device for adb devices command I guess). They are both connected to the same wifi router, same local network.

Comment: Do you adb connect to your device before removing the usb cable? please check this answer it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558830/2057782

Comment: I tried that and yes, usb debugging (adb connect) via USB works, Please read my initial post.

Comment: I tried long click on USB debugging and checked Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode (https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/94mmv1/usb_debugging_keeps_turning_off/). Not sure which one helped but now it works.

Comment: Please post you answer when you figure it out. Happy you're unblocked

Answer (score 19):

I faced the same issue and followed the instructions in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148820/android-adb-wireless-debugging-huawei-device#comment109918406_62148820) (checked Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode) and now I'm able to use wireless ADB after disconnecting the USB

Comment: Great!!! It works on my Honor View 20, I've lost a couple of hours :'(

Comment: Works on Huawei P30, thanks. But I don't get it why "Allow ADB debugging in charge only" option make it available debugging over wifi.

Comment: @YunusGedik, can you then connect to Android Studio by scanning the QR code? I do not find such option. Care to share your experience?

Comment: @texnic I do not use Android Studio. I connect via adb with terminal commands. Then Vscode recognize the device. Do not know about the QR way.